# How to change hostname, IP address via website PHP safely, CentOS

Tags: php, apache, sudo, sudoers

I'm writing a website GUI for administering a data server appliance running CentOS. A lot of appliances do this; the Vendor essentially builds GUI for changing only certain configuration parameters and locks everything else down. But I'm pretty sure I'm having problems with permissions and I'm seeking the safest way to do this. i.e. it appears that when the user submits the hostname change via the GUI, the shell_exec command is being run as apache. Apache probably doesn't have the rights to change the hostname which is why this isn't working. Granting Apache these rights can be insecure, correct? So what is the solution? How are all the appliance vendors able to write GUIs that change hostnames, how do they do it (safely)?

Code Excerpts:

```
                <form action="Settings.php" method="get">
                <div class="box">
                    <h1>Device Settings</h1>    
                     Hostname: <input type="text" name="Hostname" label="Hostname" value="<?php echo $Hostname; ?>"><br />
                     <input type="submit" value="Set"><br />
                </div>           
            </form> 
            $Hostname=shell_exec("hostname"); /*gethostname**/

            if (isset($_GET['Hostname'])){
                $Hostname=$_GET['Hostname'];
                $output1=shell_exec("sudo hostname ". $Hostname. " 2>&1");*/

            }
```

Comment: Consider what happens when I put `foo; sudo rm -r /` in the Hostname field and submit the form.

Comment: Right, so what is the solution? Should I give Apache the right to only change the host name via shell_exec (to start), and if so how? Should I just give Apache root privileges (and how?) and then just code within the PHP to ensure the host name entered doesn't include certain key words? Probably not. I'm experienced Computer Engineer, with website experience... but I've never designed an appliance GUI via html/php, I'm also less than a novice at CentOS... but I'll figure it out if you guys can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it's not secure to give apache such privileges. In this case any user on this server can run sudo and make what he want. The best way is to write a system daemon, controlled from another secured server.

If you need one-server solution, you can run another privileged apache, which doesn't serve user's virtualhosts. This will be much more secure.

Answer (score 1):

I would never tie Apache directly to system commands. Any use of `shell_exec()` should be considered a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). I would go about this by having your GUI do nothing but save its values to some simple non-privileged store, like a JSON file saved in a dedicated directory somewhere or maybe a SQLite database. This eliminates the need to give Apache any special permissions and has the added benefit that you can save multiple timestamped versions of the config, which can allow you to simply revert to any prior config in the case of an error. Then, I'd create a separate process, unrelated to the web service, that reads the config and makes the appropriate system level changes. Only this process needs heightened permissions, not the entire web server. It can be written in whatever language you like, and can be executed manually as desired, as a cron that runs at some interval, or a daemon that actively watches for changes.

Comment: This sounds, to me, like the best scenario. The service runs in the background and monitors a custom config file... anytime it detects a change to that file, it makes the change on the actual system. I can write in a number of languages, I've never written a service like this for CentOS... I already have the code to write the user input to a config file. Could you get me started on the writing the service? Keep in mind, changing the host name is just a start, 1 out of 100 things that are to be changeable from the GUI. Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks for this, getting me on the right path. I do have some questions though. Rather than writing to a file is there a way to send the running service flags? I'm thinking the way this will work is that the service should receive information from the GUI (or it can check the database for changes every x seconds). The service will also store snmp information, and command outputs, in the database at an interval set by the GUI. The GUI will retrieve that info as analytics. For making changes via the GUI, I don't think these need to be stored in the DB... can I send them straight to the service?

Comment: Also, I only found one good source of information (http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html). Everything else on google seems to be about installing services, not creating them. Do you know any sources? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can configure `sudo` to allow execution of the all commands,  one certain command or a command pattern (regex can be used too) in the name of another user (www-data for e.g.) without asking for password.

Check the [manual](http://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudoers.man.html).

Comment: I really don't think giving Apache sudo access is a great idea, and I don't think `exec` and its cousins can sudo at all without a TTY.

Comment: You restrict the command that can be executed, not anything (e.g. to `hostname [a-z]+`). I used this technique with PHP, it's working. You can execute a sudo command via PHP's exec() if sudoers is configured for it.